# Laravel returns error after deleting a record

Tags: php, laravel

I have a function like this:

```
protected function delete_failed_payment($token)
{
    $invoice = Invoice::where("owner_id",Auth::user()->owner_id)
        ->where("token",$token)
        ->where("completed","0")
        ->first();

    Invoice::destroy($invoice->id);

    return redirect("/")->withErrors("Fail!");
}
```

After calling this function, the record gets succesfully deleted, but I get this error response in return:

> UnexpectedValueException
>
> The Response content must be a string or object implementing
>   __toString(), "boolean" given.
>
> …/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php line 407

I am expecting it to redirect me to "/" but even though the record gets deleted and there seems to be no problem, it won't let me.

I have also tried this:

```
$invoice = Invoice::where("owner_id",Auth::user()->owner_id)
        ->where("token",$token)
        ->where("completed","0")
        ->delete();
```

With the same result as before.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
protected function delete_failed_payment($token)
{
    $invoice = Invoice::where("owner_id",Auth::user()->owner_id)
            ->where("token",$token)
            ->where("completed","0")
            ->first();

    Invoice::destroy($invoice->id);

    return redirect('/')
        ->withErrors(array('message' => 'Fail!'));
}
```

Comment: Nope, this is surely from destroying the query, not the return.

Comment: What is returned if you add this into your '/' view `{{ dd($errors) }}`?

Comment: Or remove the `withErrors` part of the redirect as a test.  I think the issue is the response attached to the redirect.  The delete is working successfully by the sound of it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
protected function delete_failed_payment($token)
{
    $invoice = Invoice::where("owner_id",Auth::user()->owner_id)
        ->where("token",$token)
        ->where("completed","0")
        ->first();

    $invoice->delete();

    return redirect->to("/")->withErrors("message" => "Fail!");
}
```